# Kotlin is there a native conditional also fuction

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

Does any one know of a native function like a conditional `.also`?

I find myself writing a lot of this code

```
extractProcessorCode(originalRequest)
        .also { transactionType ->
            if (transactionType == UNKNOWN) {
                logger.warn("ProcessorTransactionType unsuccessfully extracted from originalRequest for id: $id")
            }
        }
```

It would be a lot cleaner if I could write it like this

```
extractProcessorCode(originalRequest)
        .alsoIf(it == UNKNOWN) {
            logger.warn("ProcessorTransactionType unsuccessfully extracted from originalRequest for id: $id")
        }
```

It is possible to write my own function but I would rather use a native function.
Here is what I have written as a function.

```
private inline fun <T> T.alsoIf(shouldRunBlock: (T) -> Boolean, block: (T) -> Unit): T {
    if (shouldRunBlock(this)) {
        block(this)
    }
    return this
}
```

Comment: Please note your second code sample is not correct as `transactionType` is undefined - it would have to be a lambda. No, unfortunately there is no such function in the stdlib and you have to create it by yourself. There was a very similar discussion in the Kotlin forum recently: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/applyif-and-letif/26390

Comment: [Whatif package](https://github.com/skydoves/WhatIf) comes to mind